# mountall: fsck /boot [333] terminated with status 1

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, raid

I am running a Ubuntu Precise 12.04.4 LTS vm on an ESXi. Suddenly, the boot up process started crashing with the following message:

`/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-boot: 251/249856 files (6.4% non-contiguous), 168519/499712 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [333] terminated with status 1`

I also noticed that before these messages, there was a "md0: unknown partition table" message.

I went to an earlier snapshot and compared the actual fstab, blkdid and fdisk -l results and they are identical except for the "...doesn't contain a valid partition table" which show up on the working snapshot, so they should be of no concern.

I can boot into rescue mode, login with root and access all my data. All this has left stumped and would appreciate some help or ideas on how to solve this problem.

Thank you,
Joe

```
root@luxsrv:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0       1
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-boot /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0



root@luxsrv:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="a20519ce-3e01-1815-bb38-8ac88d4bc550" UUID_SUB="93e4fce8-5d9e-c4cc-9bc6-46799990f12a" LABEL="luxsrv:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="a20519ce-3e01-1815-bb38-8ac88d4bc550" UUID_SUB="4c99f697-ae34-7761-aa82-1edfa99fc535" LABEL="luxsrv:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="1gccOP-wEWz-jXXo-dVpJ-zv5l-7qvO-3uhgGU" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-boot: UUID="95a1f29d-7749-4913-81c2-31fb66ca5bfd" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-swap: UUID="00a3d999-6607-46c4-845b-0866ac3638a2" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-root: UUID="e1e7a268-2e0a-4a80-83c0-09cac49fc84b" TYPE="ext4"



root@luxsrv:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 171.8 GB, 171798691840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20886 cylinders, total 335544320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00012ceb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   335542271   167770112   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 171.8 GB, 171798691840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20886 cylinders, total 335544320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00085742

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   335542271   167770112   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 171.7 GB, 171662245888 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 41909728 cylinders, total 335277824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-boot: 511 MB, 511705088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62 cylinders, total 999424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-boot doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-swap: 4093 MB, 4093640704 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 497 cylinders, total 7995392 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-swap doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-root: 167.1 GB, 167054934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20309 cylinders, total 326279168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/luxsrv--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Have you tried running fsck on /boot?